# Amazon Pinpoint not delivering push notifications to newer model androids

Tags: push-notification, aws-amplify, aws-pinpoint

I have an app that sends push notifications through pinpoint sdk. IOS and anything under Samsung s5 receives the push notification. Samsung s7 -s8 are not receiving. Has something changed? Anyone else experiencing this problem? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Is your customer devices are running on Android O or  P  ?

Have they enabled the notification from settings for that app ?

Comment: Not sure if they're running on either O or P. Do they need to enable the notification from the settings for the app? Are they automatically turned off?

Answer (score 0):

Notifications from suspended apps

Prior to Android 9, notifications from suspended apps were canceled. Beginning with Android 9, notifications from suspended apps are hidden until the app is resumed.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0#notifications

Blocking channel groups: Users can now block entire groups of channels within the notification settings for an app. You can use the isBlocked() method to identify when a group is blocked and, as a result, not send any notifications for channels in that group.

Additionally, your app can query for current channel group settings using the new getNotificationChannelGroup() method.

Answer (score 0):

I have verified on Android P emulator with PinPoint SDK , its working fine.

There can be many cases for a user device not able to get notification :
* IF user himself has disabled the channel/group from settings.
* If user device is targeted for segment of campaign.
* If user device token is expire.

Also when an app developer calls Pinpoint SDK APIs to handleGCMCampaignPush() , they get a return object CampaignPushResult.

https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-android/docs/reference/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/pinpoint/targeting/notification/NotificationClient.CampaignPushResult.html

APP_IN_FOREGROUND
The SDK handled the message, but no notification was posted, since the app was in the foreground.

NOT_HANDLED
The message wasn't for pinpoint.

NOTIFICATION_OPENED
The SDK handled the message that indicated the local campaign notification was opened.

OPTED_OUT
The SDK handled the message, but no notification was posted, since the app was opted out.

POSTED_NOTIFICATION
The SDK handled the message and posted a local notification.

SILENT
The SDK handled the message that indicated the local campaign notification was opened.